# Rocket chat messaging from CLI

Tags: bash, messaging, rocket.chat

I have a script that find me files older that x minutes, and I want to send the output to rocket chat via a bash script. The problem is that when I enter the variable it does not post anything that a blank message:

The problem is in this line `MESSAGE=$(rc_message " ${out}`").

I does not matter if the variable is with cat or sed. same result blank

What should I add or remove?

```
set -x
source rocket.sh
prev_count=0
path=/home/Files/

find $path -type f -mmin +10 -exec ls -ltrah {}  \; > /home/out
count=$(cat /home/out | wc -l)

if [[ "$prev_count" -lt "$count" ]]; then
LOG="/home/message"
echo "This are the files that need to be deleted" >> "$LOG"
echo "+----------------------------------------+" >> "$LOG"
echo "" >> "$LOG"
cat /home/out | awk '{print $6,$7,$9}' >> "$LOG"
echo "" >>  "$LOG"
fi


# Build message example

sed 's/\s\+/\\n/g' /home/out
out= $(sed 's/\s+/\\n/g' /home/out)
echo ">>$out<<"
MESSAGE=$(rc_message " `${out}`")
#MESSAGE=$(rc_message "+/test")
echo $MESSAGE

# Send message (Important: Note the syntax!)
rc_post "${MESSAGE}"
```

Comment: Do you really want those back-quotes in the `MESSAGE=...` line? If you really need another layer of cmd-substitution, then use another `$(...)` pair. Also, unclear if `rc_message` is something defined in the sourced file `rocket.sh` or if a command available on the PATH. have your worked your way thru [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`? (And check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section as well). Good luck.

Comment: `rc_message` is defined it `rocket.sh` and is working is sending message where I want for example `MESSAGE=$(rc_message "test")` is posted but when I try to include the variable i got not result .

Comment: And what happens if you remove the single-quotes surrounding your `${out}` variable? You're certain that `${out}` has a value? ;-)?  Hmmm, looking closer at your `#Build a message example` section now. Please correct any problems found when pasting your code to https://shellcheck.net. Be sure to use `#!/bin/bash` as the first line there. Good luck.